# Is it against the rules to hand out gift codes for our game on the App Store?

Tags: app-store-connect, promotion-code

After publishing an app on iTunes you get 50 promo codes to hand out to users. This usually runs out pretty quickly. We thought we may be able to circumvent this by gifting the app to certain users using a US iTunes gift card. Does anyone know if this is against the App Store policy in any way? I read through the terms and conditions and didn't see anything about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple will get their 30% cut, so there should be no problem with that idea.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I know Apple is against people trying to "game" the App Store rankings via pay per purchase models. From what I understand, you can't leave reviews for gifted apps and they also don't count towards rankings so I don't really see how this can be bad. However, I'm also paranoid of Apple's strict App Store policy and I just want to double check that this isn't a violation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing *gift cards* and *promo codes.*

**Gift cards** are paid in advance using real money, so Apple gets 30% of the gift card value up front.
Apps bought using gift cards can receive customer reviews.

**Promo codes** are totally free, nobody earns anything.
Apps received using promo codes can **not** receive customer reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give away iTunes Gift Cards to promote your App. I wanted to do this on Twitter and Facebook to interact with the users, so I decided to contact Apple to make it all clear. Here is the reply:

```
Thanks for reaching out.

Unfortunately, iTunes Gift Cards, iTunes Codes or Apple product cannot be given out in conjunction with app promotions. That said, you’ll need to find an alternate incentive/gift for the program.

Best regards,
Promo Review
```

You can contact Apple on on this email: promoreview@apple.com